# HTML EMAIL Version

Tags: html, html-area-component

The following code i am using for HTML,

```
<table>
  
  <tr>Test Name</tr>
  <tr>Test Name 2</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Want headings and content in tabular form. So any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Step Name</th>
    <th>Approval Status</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Assing To</th>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>6 Sept</td>
    <td>Me..</td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```

Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks @MIXDML for your precious time and help. Its Working ! but there are three more columns which i need to add so i have to do in same way for all?

Comment: you can add your additional column in <th> </th> tag. refer this for more info https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Thanks again @MIXDML.